# node.js file-saver problem with saveas function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, filesaver.js

I have got an issue with [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) when I save a file.
The file is a canvas, and when I save with saveAs function is not working and return an error.

This is the code:

```
    function SaveIngotClient() {
      c.toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "test.png");
      });
    }
```

I've exported file-saver with html tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2.0.5/FileSaver.js"></script>
```

This is the code for create the canvas:

```
    var c = document.getElementById("GeneratedIngot");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
```

And finally, this is the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAs is not defined
    at index.html:293
```

How I can fix it?
Thanks and sorry for the bad English!
P.S is a Electron application

Comment: Did you import `saveAs`? `import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';`

Comment: @Isaac Can I do this even if it's an HTML file?

Comment: The exception says that there is a 'Reference Error'. In SaveIngotClient function, saveAs function is calling but it is not defined anywhere. It is a function in file-saver.js. SaveIngotClient function may work before script imported ? In addition, is it about node.js or static html ?

Comment: Yes, the function works before and is a static HTML file.